# Wordpress fatal error register_new_user function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website that is producing a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare register_new_user() in
>   /home/krasy56g/public_html/kola-maska.bg/wp-content/themes/kola-maska2/library/includes/registration.php
>   on line 104

Can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-register_new_user .. may help you..

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring a function named "register_new_user" twice in your code. It's a WordPress native function;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_new_user

So you possible should modify the name of the function at `wp-content/themes/kola-maska2/library/includes/registration.php` to another name.

Comment: tnx very fast answer :)